# How to avoid duplication of same place on a Places Reviews Website?

Tags: javascript, model, frontend, backend

I'm trying to set up a "Yellow-Pages" for hospitals, How can I prevent that the same place can have 2 pages? I thought about long,lat registration, but Google maps seems to have multiple values for the same place.

Comment: This is not a security question but a business requirement on how you define uniqueness. Is it by name and zipcode, is it by lat/long + radius etc. If you had two records, how would you say which one is valid and which one isnt?

Comment: Well, that's the real question, isn't it? I tried using the google maps "name" parameter with the unique lng,lat parameters, but I don't thinks it's unique enough. I want to minimize duplication to the minimum.

Comment: There are formulas to calculate the distance between lat/long values. If you find that the name is unique, you can calculate the distance between TWO points with the same name, and if they are close enough, you know you have a duplicate. Else its a different business. But that relies on the name being unique. On the other side, there could be multiple business on the same lat/long (Ex: an office building)

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you accept that as the answer.

Comment: I don't believe I can accept a comment as the answer, please add it as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are formulas to calculate the distance between lat/long values. If you find that the name is unique, you can calculate the distance between TWO points with the same name, and if they are close enough, you know you have a duplicate. Else its a different business. But that relies on the name being unique. On the other side, there could be multiple business on the same lat/long (Ex: an office building)